# Adding an active effect like the one Facebook uses

Tags: javascript, css, html

I liked the way how Facebook indicates an active tab on the website.
[image]

But I found out that it uses just a small image (after removing the float:left of the [Timeline] box).
[image]

I'm sure there's a way of doing without using images, only with CSS or JavaScript or both. All help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS tabs arrow on active tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439701/css-tabs-arrow-on-active-tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a CSS up arrow:

```
.arrow-up {
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-left: 150px solid transparent;
   border-right: 150px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 150px solid black;
}
```

Demo: https://codecanister.com/Project/d547eed9/2/fullscreen/b

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 1):

You would use css and javascript. Essentially you would find the route the user is on, then apply some css to your elements depending on where you are. For example, imagine all of the tabs have that little triangle image. Now imagine they all have "visibility: hidden" as a css property by default.

You can grab your current path in javascript by using window.location.pathname. Say for example on the timeline page, you want your timeline tab to have a class of active. You can do something like

```
var timeline = document.querySelector(<selector for your timeline tag>);
timeline.classList.add('active');
```

and in your css, you would have the tab with the class 'active' have a css property of "visibility: visible" instead.

So essentially all that happens is css is added or removed depending on what route we're on.

Comment: I meant I want to do it without using images, only with CSS or JavaScript or both, sorry I didn't include that on the question, I did now, Thank you for helping.